# Construction of wavelets

Tags: wavelets

So far I've gone through the theory of construction of wavelets in finite dimensional case and also got a little bit idea on wavelets on the function space ($L^2(\mathbb R)$). It is clear that all the construction are interlinked. So in order to construct wavelets on $L^2(\mathbb R)$, where do we begin or how do we start. It'll be of great help if someone provide with some insight.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which kind of wavelet transform on $L^2$: continuous or discrete time, continuous or discrete scale (that is in [CWT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_wavelet_transform) are $a,b$ continuous or discrete variables)

Comment: Do you know a good resource that explains the finite dimensional case?

Comment: I've followed book by Frazier,an introduction to wavelets through linear algebra.